# How to convert MongoDB Date.now from ISO string to UTC string?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a **CommentModel** document

```
date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
```

it returns this **2021-08-30T03:30:54.446Z**.
I wanna convert to something like this **2021-08-30 hh:mm:ss**, so what should i do? Thank u in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string date to utc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128079/convert-string-date-to-utc)

Comment: Please also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone